# change file names in a directory with a certain pattern at the beginning

Tags: shell, awk

I want to remove the numbers from the file names in one directory:

file names:

```
89_Ajohn_text_phones
3_jpegs_directory
..
```

What I would like to have

```
Ajohn_text_phones
jpegs_directory
```

I tried:

```
rename 's/^\([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]\)_//g' *
```

but I did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two `rename` tools. The one you appear to try to use is based on Perl, and as such  uses perl-style regular expressions. The escaping rules are a little different from sed; in particular, parentheses for grouping aren't escaped (escaped parentheses are literal parentheses). Use

```
rename 's/^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9])_//' *
```

or, somewhat more concisely,

```
rename 's/^[0-9]{1,2}_//' *
```

This `rename` is the default on Debian-based distributions such as Ubuntu.

The other `rename` tool is from `util-linux`, and it is a very simple tool that does not work with regexes and cannot handle this particular requirement. It is the default on, for example, Fedora-based distributions, and what's worse, those often don't even package the Perl rename. You can find the Perl rename [here](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename/) on CPAN and put it in `/usr/local/bin` if you want, but otherwise, your simplest option is probably a shell loop with `mv` and `sed`:

```
for f in *; do
    # set dest to the target file name
    # Note: using sed's extended regex syntax (-r) because it is nice.
    #       Much less escaping of metacharacters is needed. Note that
    #       sed on FreeBSD and Mac OS X uses -E instead of -r, so there
    #       you'd have to change that or use regular syntax, in which
    #       the regex would have to be written as ^[0-9]\{1,2\}_
    dest="$(echo "$f" | sed -r 's/^[0-9]{1,2}_//')"
    if [ "$f" = "$dest" ]; then
        # $f did not match pattern; do nothing
        true;
    elif [ -e "$dest" ]; then
        # avoid losing files.
        echo "$dest already exists!"
    else
        mv "$f" "$dest"
    fi
done
```

You could put this into a shell script, say `rename.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

transform="$1"
shift

for f in "$@"; do
    dest="$(echo "$f" | sed -r "$transform")"
    if [ "$f" = "$dest" ]; then
        ## do nothing
        true;
    elif [ -e "$dest" ]; then
        echo "$dest already exists!"
    else
        mv "$f" "$dest"
    fi
done
```

and call `rename.sh 's/^[0-9]{1,2}_//' *`.

One caveat remains: in

```
dest="$(echo "$f" | sed -r "$transform")"
```

there is a possibility that `"$f"` could be something that `echo` considers a command line option, such as `-n` or `-e`. I do not know a way to solve this portably (if you read this and know one, please leave a comment), but if you are in a position where tethering yourself to `bash` is not a problem, you can use `bash`'s here strings instead:

```
dest="$(sed -r "$transform" <<< "$f")"
```

(and replace the `#!/bin/sh` shebang with `#!/bin/bash`). Such files are rare, though, so as timebombs go, this is not unlikely to be a dud.

Comment: Odd, it works for me. Is the `rename` you use the `prename` from perl? It looked like you were attempting to use that, and my answer rather depends on it.

Comment: the one from Linux! I was already installed on the server! how can I check that?

Comment: Ah. That would be a Red Hat/CentOS/SuSE/Fedora server, wouldn't it? They come with the *other* `rename` from `util-linux`, which is considerably less powerful. You can probably see that with `rename -V` (which will give an error with the perl rename). It's a rather sad state of affairs, but there are two rename tools that are not at all compatible, and you appear to have the one that doesn't work with regexes. If you want, you can download the perl rename [here](http://search.cpan.org/~pederst/rename/) (or get it through cpan); in the meantime I'll edit in this problem and a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *
do
  mv "$f" "${f#*_}"
done
```

Comment: tnx alot, would you please explain me what does "$f" "${f#*_}" mean? what does ${f#*_} mean?

Comment: One is one argument to `mv`, and the other is the other argument to `mv`. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html